# Python Splitting string to find largest odd integer

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split the raw_input from the user (which consists of 10 integers) so I can find the largest odd integer. The final output should be the largest odd integer or "none" if there are no odds in the string. This code gives me a TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting error. I am using Python 2.7.

Here is what I have:

```
def uiLargestOddofTen():
    userInput = raw_input("Please enter ten integers:")
    oddList = []
    x = userInput.split()
    n = 10
    for element in x:
        y = int(element)
        while n > 0:
            if element % 2 != 0:
                oddList.append(y)
                n = n - 1
    return max(oddList)
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What's the purpose of `n`?  Why not check for `len(x) = 10` before the for loop?

Comment: What doesn't work with your code?

Comment: You haven't asked a question here.

Answer (score 3):

How about a list comprehension:

```
if len(x) == 10:
  oddList = [int(a) for a in x if int(a) % 2]
    if oddList:
      return max(oddList)
```

Assuming x needs to be 10 values long; assuming you don't need an else statement.

You don't need to check for `int(a) % 2 != 0`, because if it is zero it returns false anyway.

Comment: How about a list without odd numbers? Then `max()` will complain.

Comment: Why are you checking for length?

Comment: To fulfill OP's n = 10 condition @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 2):

The `TypeError` comes from your using the strings that come from `userInput.split()` without explicitly converting them to ints before you do math on them.  Note that the other answers fix this by surrounding their references to elements in that list with `int()` which forces a conversion of the input strings of digits to integers.

Edit:  This line:

```
if element % 2 != 0:
```

should become:

```
if y % 2 != 0:
```

Then your code will work, although some of the other answers here offer much more concise alternatives.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's an answer to his implicit question "why am I getting a TypeError?"

Comment: He probably meant to have the line `if y % 2 != 0` since he converted it to an int already

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
def solve(strs):
    inp = strs.split()
    #convert items to `int` and get a filtered list of just odd numbers
    odds = [x for x in (int(item) for item in inp) if x%2]
    #if odds is not empty use `max` on it else return None
    return max(odds) if odds else None
... 
>>> print solve('2 4 6 8 11 9 111')
111
>>> print solve('2 4 6 8')
None
```

`itertools.imap` version of the above code:

```
from itertools import imap
def solve(strs):
    inp = imap(int, strs.split())
    odds = [x for x in inp if x%2]
    return max(odds) if odds else None
... 
>>> print solve('2 4 6 8 11 9 111')
111
>>> print solve('2 4 6 8')
None
```

In [python-3.4](/questions/tagged/python-3.4), [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) [now accepts a default value](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes) that is returned when the iterable passed to it is empty. So above code can be changed to:

```
def solve(strs):
    #except `strs.split()` no other list is required here.
    inp = map(int, strs.split())
    return max((x for x in inp if x%2), default=None)
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. Is there anyway to return "none" if all of the inputs happen to be even? (in Python 2.7)

Comment: @user2751871 First solutions are python2.7 only and they are returning None if string contains only even items.(I've added examples too)

Answer (score 1):

```
max(filter(lambda x: int(x) & 1, raw_input().split()))
```

it throws an exception if there are no odd integers, so you can catch it and then return None.

An example of the complete code:

```
try:
    res = max(filter(lambda x: int(x) & 1, raw_input().split()))
except ValueError:
    res = None

print res
```